# Does deleting a LwM2M object instance implicitly delete observations under the instance?

Tags: lwm2m, oma

The LwM2M spec does not specify what happens to an object instance's observations when a server deletes the object instance.
For example, if a server has installed an observation on /5/0/3, then deletes /5/0 and subsequently creates a new /5/0, should the server assume that the observation on /5/0/3 no longer exists, and should be reinstalled?

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LWM2M observation feature is based on [RFC7641 - Observing Resources in the Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7641).

Looking at [RFC7641§3.2  Notifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7641#section-3.2), you can read :

> In the event that the resource changes in a way that would cause a
> normal GET request at that time to return a non-2.xx response (for
> example, when the resource is deleted), the server sends a
> notification with an appropriate response code (such as 4.04 Not
> Found) and removes the client's entry from the list of observers of
> the resource.  Non-2.xx responses do not include an Observe Option.

and at [RFC7641§4.2  Notifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7641#section-4.2) :

> A notification SHOULD have a 2.05 (Content) or 2.03 (Valid) response
> code.  However, in the event that the state of a resource changes in
> a way that would cause a normal GET request at that time to return a
> non-2.xx response (for example, when the resource is deleted), the
> server SHOULD notify the client by sending a notification with an
> appropriate response code (such as 4.04 Not Found) and subsequently
> MUST remove the associated entry from the list of observers of the
> resource.

(Note in LWM2M, the LWM2M client acts as a  CoAP server and vice versa )

So In a general way,  I understand that if the object instance is deleted (for any reason), the LWM2M client (CoAP server) should send a **4.04 Not Found**, then removes the observation relation. I guess  LWM2M server  (CoAP client) should also consider the relation is removed when he received a notification with a non-2.xx response code.

> For example, if a server has installed an observation on /5/0/3, then deletes /5/0 and subsequently creates a new /5/0, should the server assume that the observation on /5/0/3 no longer exists, and should be reinstalled?

I understand it should reinstall.

(I already answer to this at : https://github.com/OpenMobileAlliance/OMA_LwM2M_for_Developers/issues/558)